# Unable to load gems in cloud 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cloud9-ide, signer

I cannot load many ruby gems in Cloud 9's ruby on rails.

For example I run

```
$ gem install signer
```

and get:

```
Successfully installed signer-1.4.2
1 gem installed
```

but then when I try to call it with:

```
require "signer"
```

I get the following error upon running:

```
cannot load such file -- signer
```

I am getting desperate, any help would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line to the Gemfile within your Rails folder:

```
gem 'signer', '~> 1.4.2'
```

and then running `bundle install` should remove the error.